# Clean package.json before packing

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Let's say you have a npm project with the following `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "XXX",
  "version": "YYY",
  "license": "ZZZ",
  "scripts": {
    "scriptA": "...",
    "scriptB": "...",
    "preinstall": "...",
    "postinstall": "..."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "depA": "vA",
    "depB": "vB"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "depC": "vC",
    "depD": "vD"
  }
}
```

When packing/publishing your package, you don't need the `scripts` or `devDependencies` keys. But more dangerously, the `preinstall` and `postinstall` scripts could trigger weird/unwanted actions when people install your package as a dependency.

**So how do you clean your `package.json`, ie remove the keys that you don't need?**

I'm currently using npm 3.10. If I use the `npm pack` command, according to the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack) it will simply pack the current package if no arguments are provided (therefore taking the raw `package.json` from disk) and there is no options I can provide to clean it up.

I can of course write my own scripts that would zip the package and generate my own `package.json`. Is it the way to go?

Answer (score 4):

I have created [`clean-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clean-package) to do this.

The most simple usage is just three steps:

1. `npm install clean-package --save-dev`
2. Hook `clean-package` into the `prepack` and `postpack` scripts

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "prepack": "clean-package",
     "postpack": "clean-package restore"
   }
   ```
3. Configure `clean-package` as root property in your `package.json`

   ```json
   "clean-package": {
     "remove": [
       "script",
       "devDependencies"
     ]
   }
   ```

There are many more options and extended uses, so there is more information on the repo: https://github.com/roydukkey/clean-package.

Comment: Thank you for publishing this, it was quite useful to work around tooling issues - namely `tsc` `moduleResolution` and this strange in-between state we find ourselves with esm.  We used the clean-package api in our light tooling over lerna-lite to process our monorepo.

Answer (score 3):

Using npm itself, this does not seem possible. As of npm 3.10, `npm publish` or `npm pack` will indeed just include a pure copy of your `package.json` in your tgz.

The solution is therefore to **generate its own packaged file** to have full control over the included `package.json`.

## Basic example

Note: this is using the shell and synchronous method from npm `fs`

```
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');

const shell = require('shelljs');
const targz = require('tar.gz');

// create temp directory
const tempDirectory = fs.mkdtempSync(`${os.tmpdir()}/your-project-tarball-`);
const packageDirectory = `${tempDirectory}/package`;

// create subfolder package
fs.mkdirSync(packageDirectory);

// read existing package.json
const packageJSON = require('./package.json');

// copy all necessary files
// https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files
shell.cp('-R', packageJSON.files, packageDirectory);
shell.cp('-R', ['README.md', 'CHANGELOG.md', 'LICENSE'], packageDirectory);

// create your own package.json or modify it here
Reflect.deleteProperty(packageJSON, 'scripts');
fs.writeFileSync(`${packageDirectory}/package.json`, JSON.stringify(packageJSON, null, 2));

// create tgz and put it in dist folder
targz().compress(packageDirectory, 'your-package.tgz');
```

## Real life example with Lodash

This is for example what the `lodash` lib does in version 4.17.2. Their original `package.json` looks like (cf https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.2/package.json):

```
{
  "name": "lodash",
  "version": "4.17.2",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "main": "lodash.js",
  "engines": { "node": ">=4.0.0" },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run build:main && npm run build:fp",
    "build:fp": "node lib/fp/build-dist.js",
    "build:fp-modules": "node lib/fp/build-modules.js",
    "build:main": "node lib/main/build-dist.js",
    "build:main-modules": "node lib/main/build-modules.js",
    "doc": "node lib/main/build-doc github && npm run test:doc",
    "doc:fp": "node lib/fp/build-doc",
    "doc:site": "node lib/main/build-doc site",
    "doc:sitehtml": "optional-dev-dependency marky-markdown@^9.0.1 && npm run doc:site && node lib/main/build-site",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "style": "npm run style:main && npm run style:fp && npm run style:perf && npm run style:test",
    "style:fp": "jscs fp/*.js lib/**/*.js",
    "style:main": "jscs lodash.js",
    "style:perf": "jscs perf/*.js perf/**/*.js",
    "style:test": "jscs test/*.js test/**/*.js",
    "test": "npm run test:main && npm run test:fp",
    "test:doc": "markdown-doctest doc/*.md",
    "test:fp": "node test/test-fp",
    "test:main": "node test/test",
    "validate": "npm run style && npm run test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "async": "^2.1.2",
    "benchmark": "^2.1.2",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "cheerio": "^0.22.0",
    "codecov.io": "~0.1.6",
    "coveralls": "^2.11.15",
    "curl-amd": "~0.8.12",
    "docdown": "~0.7.1",
    "dojo": "^1.11.2",
    "ecstatic": "^2.1.0",
    "fs-extra": "~1.0.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.1",
    "istanbul": "0.4.5",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "jscs": "^3.0.7",
    "lodash": "4.17.1",
    "lodash-doc-globals": "^0.1.1",
    "markdown-doctest": "^0.9.0",
    "optional-dev-dependency": "^2.0.0",
    "platform": "^1.3.3",
    "qunit-extras": "^3.0.0",
    "qunitjs": "^2.0.1",
    "request": "^2.78.0",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.2",
    "sauce-tunnel": "^2.5.0",
    "uglify-js": "2.7.4",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  },
  "greenkeeper": {
    "ignore": [
      "lodash"
    ]
  }
}
```

But the published `package.json` looks like (cf https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.2/package.json)

```
{
  "name": "lodash",
  "version": "4.17.2",
  "description": "Lodash modular utilities.",
  "keywords": "modules, stdlib, util",
  "homepage": "https://lodash.com/",
  "repository": "lodash/lodash",
  "icon": "https://lodash.com/icon.svg",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "lodash.js",
  "author": "John-David Dalton <john.david.dalton@gmail.com> (http://allyoucanleet.com/)",
  "contributors": [
    "John-David Dalton <john.david.dalton@gmail.com> (http://allyoucanleet.com/)",
    "Mathias Bynens <mathias@qiwi.be> (https://mathiasbynens.be/)"
  ],
  "scripts": { "test": "echo \"See https://travis-ci.org/lodash/lodash-cli for testing details.\"" }
}
```

where you can see the `scripts` and `devDependencies` keys for example are not there anymore. This is done using a JavaScript Template [package.jst](https://github.com/lodash/lodash-cli/blob/master/template/package.jst) as long as a nodejs script [Lodash CLI](https://github.com/lodash/lodash-cli/blob/4.17.2/bin/lodash)